# Show salesforce user public image outside SFDC

Tags: php, rest, salesforce

I am getting salesforce `Users.SmallPhotoUrl` and show it on my `php` page using `rest` api. But it works only if you are logged into Salesforce in same browser.

Any workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After so much try, i found out the solution which is you can pass `access_token` along with the `Users.SmallPhotoUrl` in format like `https://path_to_salesforce_image?oauth_token=your_acccess_token`

Hope it works for you guys